# post SelectSeasonType.Html Seelct box value into AddressDate.Html, and then check if SeasonTypeId matches

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have two Html Pages: AddressDate.Html, SelectSeasonType.Html

AddressDate.Html holds jquery for autocomplete on textbox for user to get suggestions of their address when tying in textbox
   $(document).ready(function () {

```
              $('#textbox').autocomplete({
                   source: 'PickupHandler.ashx',
                   minLength: 5,
                   select: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#textbox').val(ui.item.label);
                    var seasontype = $('#seasonid').val(ui.item.value2);
                    var textinside = $('#addressid').val(ui.item.value);

                }
            });
```

SelectSeasonType.Html has a basic Select box for the Admin to be able to select a seasonTypeID and based on the value, AddressDate.Html autocomplete should only generate the sleected SeasontypeID of suggestions.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#seasontype_select').change(function () {
                var selectedval = $(this).val();
                $('#showit').html(selectedval);
            });
        });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <select id="seasontype_select">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Brush Pickup</option>
        <option value="2"> Leaf Pickup </option>
    </select>
    <div id="showit">

    </div>
</body>
```

in AddressDate.Html the jquery variable seasontype holds the SeasonTypeID

```
// var seasontype = $('#seasonid').val(ui.item.value2);
```

so is there a way to match the Id's from select box? and render data in autocomplete based on that?